# X937 file decoding in golang?

Tags: go, decoding

I am trying to open and parse an x937 file - which I BELIEVE is usually encoded in EBCDIC 0037.

I am using the following library to decode the main bytes of the file :

```
"github.com/gdumoulin/goebcdic"
```

and the code I am using is as follows, for now.

```
// Bytes in file.
b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("testingFile.x937")
fmt.Println(string(goebcdic.ASCIItoEBCDICofBytes(b)))
```

But if I dump the output of my file, I still don't seem to get anything that matches what I would have thought I would be looking for.

Any ideas on how I can work with this?

Comment: Do you mean an X9.37 (Image Cash Letter) file? This is a binary file format, which contains some fields which are in EBCDIC. You should read its specification and treat it accordingly.

Comment: yeah, that is what I mean, been working on trying to get it read in so that I can parse it - but I don't seem to be able to parse the whole file as EBCDIC to ASCII - so that is why I can't loop over the data...

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/gdumoulin/goebcdic/blob/master/goebcdic.go) suggests if the source file, testingFile.x937, is binary EBCDIC, you should use 'EBCDICtoASCIIofBytes', no?